# Workflow - item creation failure + troubleshooting techniques

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, designer-workflow

So, I was following this pretty closely: 
http://365hq.net/creating-folders-and-sub-folders-using-sharepoint-2010-designer-workflow/

But for some reason, it is not working. I thought I have did everything right, but I must be missing something. I was trying to troubleshoot it myself, but I am not familiar what the best way to go is with doing so on a workflow since there are no traditional debugging tools available. Any suggestions on how I should tackle this issue?

First try - does not follow the link steps precisely, and it didn't work. Create new folder is a site workflow in this case:

[image: First try - does not follow the link steps precisely, and it didn't work. Create new folder is a site workflow in this case]

Second try - almost exactly the same as the instructions, but it seems like there is still something missing. Not sure how I should even troubleshoot it...

[image: Second try - almost exactly the same as the instructions, but it seems like there is still something missing. Not sure how I should even troubleshoot it...]

Comment: Does the workflow even trigger? If yes, what is the error message that you get?

Comment: Yes, I believe the workflow did trigger for version #1 above since the log successfully executed. But the error generated is... Useless. It just said "an error has occured in "Create Test Plan Folder". Version #2 did not generate any items within workflow history log, so it is possible that it has not executed. I don't know why there should be a difference between the two though.